# if statement multiple or operator to separate characters of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement, or-operator

So i am writting something that takes a string and then perform a loop on each of that string character. I have an if statement to separate numbers from symbols with a bunch of or operators in condition but it dosen't seem to work.

```
equation = '2+5-4*6-2/2'

for x in equation:
    if x == ('+' or '-') or ('*' or '/'):
        print('symbol', x)
    else:
        print(x)
```

The output:

```
symbol 2
symbol +
symbol 5
symbol -
symbol 4
symbol *
symbol 6
symbol -
symbol 2
symbol /
symbol 2
```

I actually have a solution, wich is this:

```
equation = '2+5-4*6-2/2'
symbols = ['+','-','*','/']

for x in equation:
    if x in symbols:
        print('symbol', x)
    else:
        print(x)
```

But i still want to know why the or operators dont work.
I have tried these condition and doesn't work.

```
if x == ('+' or '-') or ('*' or '/'):
if x == (('+' or '-') or ('*' or '/')):
if x == '+' or '-' or '*' or '/':
```

I would like to know more, thanks.

Comment: `('+' or '-')` is or-ing two characters; since neither is falsey, the expression as a whole is true.

Comment: `or` is not an extension of the `==` operator; it is an operator in its own right. `'+' or '-'` evaluates to `'+'` before the comparison ever occurs.

Comment: Thanks guys i get it now.